# fill in missing rows without a unique id

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make this dataframe:

```
 type value
    A     1
    B     5
    C     3
    D     2
    B     0
    C     7
    A     2
    B     5
    C     9
    C     4
```

into this:

```
 type value
    A     1
    B     5
    C     3
    D     2
    A  <NA>
    B     0
    C     7
    D  <NA>
    A     2
    B     5
    C     9
    D  <NA>
    A  <NA>
    B  <NA>
    C     4
    D  <NA>
```

Code to make dfs

```r
df <- data.frame(type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'), value = c('1', '5', '3', '2', '0', '7', '2', '5', '9', '4'))
df2 <- data.frame(type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), value = c('1', '5', '3', '2', NA, '0', '7', NA, '2', '5', '9', NA, NA, NA, '4', NA))
```

Is there anyway to group by each group of distinct types, and append the missing row with type and value = NA?

The difficult part of this is that there is no unique id to group by and expand.

I have looked into expand() and complete() and I am still having trouble.

Also if there any way to apply this to a vector of types? e.g. if I wanted to add E into each group as well, I can pass in c('A','B','C','D','E').

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a unique `ID` like this and use `complete` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = match(type, unique(type)), 
         ID = cumsum(ID - lag(ID, default = first(ID)) <= 0)) %>%
  complete(ID, type)

#      ID type  value
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 A     1    
# 2     1 B     5    
# 3     1 C     3    
# 4     1 D     2    
# 5     2 A     NA   
# 6     2 B     0    
# 7     2 C     7    
# 8     2 D     NA   
# 9     3 A     2    
#10     3 B     5    
#11     3 C     9    
#12     3 D     NA   
#13     4 A     NA   
#14     4 B     NA   
#15     4 C     4    
#16     4 D     NA
```

Comment: This is great! But is there any way to apply this to a vector of unique types? e.g. if I wanted to add E into each group.

Comment: @MatthewLee You can save the unique values in a vector `vec <- c('A','B','C','D','E')` and change the last line in my answer to `complete(ID, type = vec)`